# Thresholded binary image appears to be corrupted

Tags: .net, opencv, image-processing, visual-c++

I am doing a project using opencv and at a certain stage I threshold an image to get a binary image. But after displaying that binary image, it appears to be corrupted with unwanted black areas at the middle. Is it because of some memory corruption? Or limitations of my VGA card?
or any other reason? Please help. I've attached a snap here.

actually my code is like quite big so I'd only post the relevant code segment here.

```
int printDefectThrshTemp = avgPixelIntensity1.val[0]*1.3 + threshPrint - 100;
    if (printDefectThrshTemp > 255) printDefectThrshTemp = 255;
    if (printDefectThrshTemp <1) printDefectThrshTemp = 1;
    Mat resizedBadgeThresholded;
    threshold(resizedBadgeTaken,resizedBadgeThresholded,printDefectThrshTemp,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

[image]

Original image is one of the badges extracted from the template shown.
[image]

Comment: Can you post the original image?

Comment: @berak I added the code segment

Comment: @KeillRandor added the original image

Comment: can you display/save that badge in full size? maybe the corruption occurs during extraction/copy of the badge?!?

Comment: (add a `imshow` or `imwrite` with `resizedBadgeTaken` as input parameter) and analyze or post that image please. Or post the code that generates `resizedBadgeTaken` from the template.